# Getting back to an old revision in SVN

Tags: command-line, svn

The thing is that the revision number 4 was working good. The team did some changes in the last week and when I came back, they are in the 14th revision.
I updated, but there are some conflicts and now I can't run my app in Rails.
In my working folder I have all the revisions (until 14) but I only want the revision 4.

I tried doing `svn up -r4` and it did not work. When opening the Rails app, there is the current code.

**How can I erase all the revisions (from 5 to 14) and have only the revision 4 in my working folder?**

System: Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: What client software do you use?

Comment: No client I think. I do all per command line.

Answer (score 2):

To "revert" to rev. 4, try the following commands:

```
svn merge -r:14:4 http://my.repository.com/my/project/trunk
svn commit -m "Reverted to revision 4."
```

Source: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Comment: I do not want to change anything in the repository (server). I just want to work with revision 4 in my working directory. Should I use only: svn merge -r:14:4 http://my.repository.com/my/project/trunk without commit?

Comment: Thxs for you answer. I got it. With svn update -r 4 works. I do not know why it did not work before.

Comment: You know that you can use git as an svn client locally, right?

Comment: Yes @Velkan. The point is that we have our own servers.

Comment: The original question is not about the servers, but about the working folder. And the svn client is not the right tool for managing your working folder nowadays.

Comment: Why is that @Velkan?

Comment: Because git client is compatible with svn server. Git is better supported, used by more people, has very important features like 'rebase'. It's a bit off topic, just some information about what is considered obsolete, what is industry standard and how painlessly move towards the standard.